# Input image on access front end connected to sql server

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have sql server 2014 as back end to store images, front end is access 2016 and both are connected through ODBC connection, all data fields work perfectly except for image. Here is my problem, in the linked table on access i see image data type as "OLE Object" and in sql server it is set as "image". I want data type to be changed as "attachment" in access, and im unable to edit the table. The reason i want data type to be attachment is because 1) image input is lot easier 2) Generate image perview in the original format 3) OLE will bloat the size because it converts image to bitmap. Pls suggest what's the best way to input image without using OLE object.

Answer (score 0):

Store the images in the filesystem and just store the path to the image in the database or you have to use VARBINARY(Max) or OLE, you can't use the attachment type in mssql.

Comment: I used VARBINARY(MAX) in sql server and thanks for your response. I found a tool called dbpix which gave a workaround, with this tool i can attach images and have them previewed just like the attachment data type in access, only disadvantage is this is not free and will leave watermark on images which is fine for me :)

Comment: If `dbpix` fits your needs, OK. But with storing only the path, you keep your database,small, if you store many images.and you can open them without the database.

Comment: Thank you, size is not a constraint because i use sql server as backend. As of now dbpix works fine :)